# Distinguish between this "and" that or this "or" that

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Just wondering about this sentence I came across:

> It is difficult to distinguish between a misrepresentation or an exaggeration.

I feel *'and'* should be used in place of *'or'*. Can someone confirm this and provide an explanation?

Comment: This is a peculiarity of the predicate _distinguish between_. It takes two objects in a conjoined phrase, but either conjunction (_and, or_) can be used. _And_ is licensed by the construction _between X and Y_, and _or_ is licensed by the meaning, which involves a binary choice between two alternatives, hence _or_. Individual predicates can have little affordances like this.

Comment: If I'm going to compare things, they have to be plural. I'm not going to distinguish something from itself. The choice word *or* leaves me with only one thing. Not a fan. It's the word *between* that asks for plural. Maybe I'll travel between Paris or Nice ... and where?

Comment: _Or_ seems illogical to me. You distinguish _between_ two things - A and B.

Comment: That's the _between A and B_ construction, with a Bridge metaphor. But distinguishing is really choosing, and one chooses A or B, with no _and_ bridge between them.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms occur (and they definitely *mean* exactly the same), but ***and*** [is more common than](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=distinguish%20between%20this%20and%20that%2Cdistinguish%20between%20this%20or%20that&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdistinguish%20between%20this%20and%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistinguish%20between%20this%20or%20that%3B%2Cc0) ***or*** in the cited context...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/590499/349876) both conjunctions are used, but "or" is used much less; out of ten dictionaries  there is not a single one to record "or" (neither in the definition nor in the examples). Only "and" is specifically mentioned (definition), and only in OALD; this is nevertheless an indication that "or" is not being perceived as acceptable.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/distinguish?q=distinguish) **distinguish between A and B** recognize the difference between two people or things

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distinguish)) **in British English** 1. (when intr, foll by *between* or *among*)
> to make, show, or recognize a difference or differences (between or among); differentiate (between)

> ([MerriamWebster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinguish))  to perceive a difference

> ([Cambnridge Dictionry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/distinguish))  to **recognize the difference between two things or two people**

> ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/distinguish)) 1.1 *no object* Recognize or point out a difference.
> ‘we must distinguish between two kinds of holiday’

> ([McMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/distinguish))  ntransitive/transitive to recognize the differences between things

> ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=distinguish)) To perceive or indicate differences; discriminate: Can the child distinguish between right and wrong?

> ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/distinguish)) verb (used without object)
> to indicate or show a difference (usually followed by between)

> ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/distinguish)) to recognize and understand the difference between two or more things or people SYN differentiatedistinguish between

> (SOED) **II** *v.i.* **9** Perceive or mark  the difference between things, discriminate, make a mental distonction, *between*.

What is to be noticed in this set of references is the fact that all, mostly explicitly, show that the preposition used after this verb is "between", or, as Collins shows, more rarely, "among".

[image]

One is to understand that "among" is entirely equivalent to "between", except that usage prefers "between" when there are only two elements; it is also the case that "among" and "between" are used together, and that then "among" has the function to make precise a set within which the comparisons are made between two types.

(*[among](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22distinguish%20among%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)*)

- Distinguish among a scientific hypothesis, a scientific theory, and a scientific law (law of nature).
- The most typical is to distinguish among organizations according to characteristics that correspond to their strategies,
- If there are a lot of dogs spread out evenly in a halfcircle in front of us, how many could we distinguish among?
- To further distinguish, among the three: inspiration, illumination and revelation.
- our experience suggests that it will be important to distinguish among three DUR functions
- We distinguish among those living alone between husband - wife ( HWPNF ) and lone - parent ( LPPNF ) units . We distinguish among families in shared accommodation, between primary nuclear families ( PNFP ) and others
- they distinguish among the various “ logical elements ” on the basis of characteristics of their roles in inference that are associated

"Between" is used also just as "among", that is, it is used for sets in which more than two elements have to be distinguished from one another.

(*[between](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22distinguish%20between%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)*)

- These age differences are not contrary to Turiel's claim that all children across different ages can distinguish between different social domains. (*"Among" could be used just as well as "between"*.)
- elements are distinctive in that they incorporate sound features that enable us to distinguish between spoken words. For example, the word bad has three phonemes. If we change the first, we can distinguish between bad and sad.
- can we increase our ability to know everything, and to distinguish between the truth, the good and the

This tends to show a fairly close equivalence between "between" and "among", as the Collins dictionary mentions  (foll by *between* or *among*).

The case for an equivalence between "between" and "among" shows that "distinguish between A and B" is the same thing as saying "distinguish among/between the elements of the set comprising A and B"; here "set comprising A *or* B" would not be meaningful; it would be complete nonsense to tolerate that either A or B could be missing from the set. In the end, it can be said that the use of "or" is not logical.